# change div data-src to image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

How do I change div data-src to image_tag?

```
div data-src="images/index_slide01.jpg">
```

I tried this :

```
%= image_tag "index_slide01.jpg", data: { src: "index_slide01"} %>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What language are you using? Please add it as a tag.

Comment: what do u mean by image_tag?

Comment: @nour Why would you want to add a src attribute to a `div` ??

Answer (score 0):

you can have a html structure like below :

```
<img src="add the gif image" data-src="add the actual image you want loaded">
```

and then add some fancy JS code like below :

```
$(function () {

    str_src = $('img').data('src');

    console.log(str_src);
    var source = $('img').attr('data-src');
    console.log(source);

    if (source) {
        setTimeout(function(){
              $('img').attr("src", source);    
        },2000);    
    };

});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE .](http://jsfiddle.net/5mv66sf4/3/)**